# ReactJS theory render state recursion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Can we change state variables inside of the render() function without, re-invoking render() function??

When I try this, it appears to call render() recursively.  Is this best practice?

Example:

```
constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state = {
           maxWidth: `${window.innerWidth - 100}px`
       }
    }
    .
    .
    .
    render() {
       const defaultTabCheck = () => {
           if (this.props.tabsProperties.length > 0) {
               this.setState({
                   maxWidth: `${window.innerWidth - 72}px`
               })
           }
       }

       return (
           <span style={‌{ width: this.state.maxWidth }}>
    .
```

Answer (score 1):

from the react docs

> The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify component state, it returns the same result each time it’s invoked, and it does not directly interact with the browser. If you need to interact with the browser, perform your work in componentDidMount() or the other lifecycle methods instead. Keeping render() pure makes components easier to think about.

for this check you should just do it in your constructor and in `componentWillReceiveProps` for whenever props change.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {
       maxWidth: props.tabsProperties.length > 0 ? `${window.innerWidth - 72}px` : `${window.innerWidth - 100}px`
   }
}


componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.tabsProperties.length > 0 && this.props.tabsProperties.length === 0) {
     this.setState({
         maxWidth: `${window.innerWidth - 72}px`
     })
   }
 }
```

You should never update state in the render function, its an anti-pattern and even if you used a `shouldComponentUpdate` to protect against recursion its not a best practice. Instead use the life cycle methods that react provides whose purpose is respond to state/prop changes and act accordingly.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render

Comment: thanks for the response!

Suppose we dispatch an action to retrieve data from redux, and then needed to set state variables.

How do you set those state variables, without invoking the render? Is it possible?

Comment: Once you are using redux then you have a global state (you can still have component state but usually you will be using the redux global state). You dispatch actions when you want to update the store state not retrieve data. If you want your component to get data from the redux store it would need to use the `mapStateToProps` functionality redux provides to map specific store state to be a prop of the component.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't update state in render method. Move that in 
`componentWillReceiveProps` method instead. For more information, read this [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html).